# With Cassandra, Why would 1000 op/sec produce 400MB/s of I/O in the layout below?

Tags: performance, cassandra, performance-testing

This is a read-heavy workload (85% read, 15% write) on a 3.3 billlion record dataset and I'm pulling 450MB/sec from a SATA SSD (maxing out the controller) but only getting ~1000 ops/s.  I don't think it should be doing that much I/O, but I'm new to Cassandra and don't really understand why it would be doing that.

```
Keyspace: stresscql
    Read Count: 81263974
    Read Latency: 37.271172120563534 ms.
    Write Count: 18576806
    Write Latency: 0.01787069736315274 ms.
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: u
            SSTable count: 251
            SSTables in each level: [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            Space used (live): 1712307458381
            Space used (total): 1712307458381
            Space used by snapshots (total): 0
            Off heap memory used (total): 3358807452
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.6798834918759787
            Number of keys (estimate): 3354476152
            Memtable cell count: 0
            Memtable data size: 0
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0
            Memtable switch count: 10
            Local read count: 81263974
            Local read latency: 40.886 ms
            Local write count: 18576806
            Local write latency: 0.020 ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 2097321112
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 2715609520
            Index summary off heap memory used: 633723580
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 9474352
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 51
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 72
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 72
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0000004430007106
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 10
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1



### DML ###

keyspace: stresscql

keyspace_definition: |
   CREATE KEYSPACE stresscql WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};

table: u

table_definition: |
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS u (
    c uuid,
    f bigint,
    i boolean,
    bl boolean,
    t timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY(c,f, i)
  ) WITH compaction = { 'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' }
  AND compression = { 'crc_check_chance' : 1.0, 'sstable_compression' : 'SnappyCompressor' }

### Column Distribution Specifications ###

columnspec:
  - name: c

  - name: f

  - name: i

  - name: bl

  - name: t

### Batch Ratio Distribution Specifications ###

insert:
  partitions: fixed(1)
  select:    fixed(1)/1
  batchtype: UNLOGGED

queries:
   selectuser:
      cql: select * from u where c = ? and f = ? and i = ?
      fields: samerow
   newselect:
      cql: select bl from u where c = ? and f = ? and i = ?
```

Also tried with LeveledCompactionStrategy and this is what I get - still clearly constrained on I/O:

```
This row would've been cached (not using row-cache, but whatever other caching happens), since I had to select it to get the guid value for 'c'.

cqlsh> select * from stresscql.u where c = 2953e0ef-44fd-44fb-8d3e-8a2498ae694f;

 c                                    | f           | i    | bl   | t
--------------------------------------+-------------+------+------+--------------------------
 2953e0ef-44fd-44fb-8d3e-8a2498ae694f | 58180117557 | True | True | 2016-05-07 09:43:07+0000

(1 rows)

Tracing session: dd78f580-32ff-11e6-8746-45b1db7c6f51

 activity                                                                                                                                  | timestamp                  | source       | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                                                                        Execute CQL3 query | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.512000 | 10.7.137.139 |              0
 Parsing select * from stresscql.u where c = 2953e0ef-44fd-44fb-8d3e-8a2498ae694f; [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.512000 | 10.7.137.139 |             92
                                                                                                 Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-1] | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.512000 | 10.7.137.139 |            208
                                             Executing single-partition query on u [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.513000 | 10.7.137.139 |           1626
                                                                                        Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.513000 | 10.7.137.139 |           1677
                                                              Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 15405 [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.514000 | 10.7.137.139 |           1944
                                           Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.514000 | 10.7.137.139 |           2401
                                                                          Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-2] | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.514000 | 10.7.137.139 |           2445
                                                                                                                          Request complete | 2016-06-15 15:48:39.543778 | 10.7.137.139 |          31778


Keyspace: stresscql
        Read Count: 115672739
        Read Latency: 37.24272796733031 ms.
        Write Count: 25113006
        Write Latency: 0.016802926260599788 ms.
        Pending Flushes: 0
                Table: user_identified_caller_by_telephone
                SSTable count: 847
                SSTables in each level: [1, 10, 100, 736, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                Space used (live): 2032182537714
                Space used (total): 2032182537714
                Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                Off heap memory used (total): 2540382332
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.6868674726322842
                Number of keys (estimate): 3361569503
                Memtable cell count: 1162671
                Memtable data size: 42639539
                Memtable off heap memory used: 0
                Memtable switch count: 12
                Local read count: 115672739
                Local read latency: 40.854 ms
                Local write count: 25113006
                Local write latency: 0.019 ms
                Pending flushes: 0
                Bloom filter false positives: 1
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                Bloom filter space used: 2115703120
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 2115696344
                Index summary off heap memory used: 418366956
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 6319032
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 51
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 72
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 72
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0000007348317013
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 50
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1

----------------
```

Comment: what version of cassandra?

Comment: ReleaseVersion: 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading this wrong but I think you are creating just one giant partition which will be really slow compactions. Theres a lot of this in the newer versions (3.6, 3.7) in tickets like [CASSANDRA-11206](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11206) so be sure to be using the latest as there is some recent improvements that will help a bit. You will probably want to change your `partitions: fixed(1)` and `select` in stress profile to make your data distributed more.

Probably have a bit tied up in compactions getting behind (low default throughput) leading to each read having to touch a lot of sstables. 251 is a lot for STCS since with the wide partitions it will likely have to read from each one.

With that data model and workload (stress profile issues aside) should probably try LeveledCompactionStrategy and increase your compaction throughput (can test different with `nodetool setcompactionthroughput`, I would start with something like 64 but can move it up and down to see how it affects your workload). The compactions will take more IO but then your reads will take less which for your workload is better.

Comment: According to http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improved-cassandra-2-1-stress-tool-benchmark-any-schema that section partitions: fixed(1) means that during an insert batch, only one partition key will be inserted at a time.  The actual partitioning should be based on the value/cardinality of the first element of the primary key (the column called "c"), right?

No compactions were running while testing.  I've also tested with the LeveledCompactionStrategy and performance was very similar, but compaction time was greatly increased - a major compaction took over a week!

Comment: One other thing to note.  After a major compaction, the sstables were combined down to 3 and performance was still as described above.

As for partitioning as well - this is a single instance of cassandra on a single node - does partitioning even come into play?

Comment: ah your right (its right there in the stats even I just wasnt looking close enough). So actually `Local write latency: 0.020 ms` writes seem good its just reads: `Local read latency: 40.886 ms`. The giant bloom filter may be an issue, switching to LCS lets you basically get rid of that. May even be tied to having sooooo many partitions that the index summary is too spread out, increasing index_summary_capacity_in_mb may give more room (id do it after BF reduction). Beyond that (and possible jvm tuning) I would probably recommend using perf tool like yourkit.

Comment: probably shouldnt do major compactions in tests since you wont be (shouldnt be) using them in production ever. (yes partitions are on `c` btw).

Comment: Regarding the bloom filter, aren't they stored wholly in memory?  With a 0% FP rate and bloom filter in memory, that doesn't explain the I/O.  450MB/s for 1000 op/s seems high.  That's ~450k per read of a column < 63 bytes wide.  That's the thing I don't understand.  https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadPathForUsers says the main I/O would be scanning the partition summary, then scanning a tiny part of the pkey index, then getting data based on the index.  I changed to leveled, and total throughput is stil ~1000 op/s. I'll add more info to the question about timing/cfstats now.